# Getting the instructions and addressing modes from a binary?

Tags: binary, assembly, hex

I am revisiting assembly, and there are many, many more instructions on x86 than my previous work with SPARCs.  In short, I'm going to write some function that are assembly-inline to handle some speedups that the compiler is just doing poorly (there's no overflow bit in C).  Anyway, for this reason, I am interested in the types of instructions that are generally and the addressing modes in a static context.

Is there a better tool than objdump for this?  I hacked together objdump and awk, but I feel there's a better way.

Comment: Wouldn't be StackOverflow a better site for this question?

Comment: @polemon maybe, but generally, I'm using unix tools, so I thought this would be better.  If the mods think that it would be better at stackoverflow, I'll happily post it there.

Comment: Ray Seyfarth has a nice book on Intel assembly (https://rayseyfarth.com/asm/).  You can get the PDF for a pretty reasonable price.  Otherwise I'm sure there are a ton of other references on the Internet.

Comment: A binary is already compiled to machine code for a specific ISA.  At that point it's too late to make any decisions about what inline asm to use.  Use CPP macros like `#ifdef __x86_64__`.  (On most ISAs including x86, no new addressing modes get added by extensions, other than whole new modes like 64-bit mode.  [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34058101)).  For instructions, again CPP macros like `#ifdef __BMI2__`